# Type error : Keys must be a string when creating a file in a specific folder in drive

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm using python with GAE, i'm trying to create a file in a specfic folder.
Here is the code i've been using:

```
    ...
    drive= build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

    body = {
        'title': 'title', 
        'description': 'description',
        'mimetype': 'text/plain'
    }

    body['parents'] = [{id: str(drive_state.folderid)}]
    file = drive.files().insert(body=body).execute() 
    ...
```

I get the Keys Must Be A String type error (in the last line).
what i'm I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your body parents must contain a key that is a string. So try placing your id in quotes

```
body['parents'] = [{'id': str(drive_state.folderid)}]
```

You can find more information and example here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert